# How to disable newsfeed notifications only for private communities

Tags: community

Has someone noticed that when creating a private community (in SP 2013) and answering to a topic a notification appears in the newsfeed(also called microfeed). From my understanding the purpose of a private community is, that it is hidden and not accessable for all users except that one a moderator actively invites.

So is there a possibility to only prevent the newsfeed entries of **private** communities?
I would like to keep the setting "Participation in communities" under the newsfeed settings enabled to get notifications of "visible" communities.